# Mask a url in java

Tags: jsp, url-rewriting

how to mask a url in java web application? I have a url like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/onlinestore/customer/order.jsp
```

i want that url to be displayed in url box of a browser as

`http://localhost:8080/onlinestore/order.aspx`

how t o do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: The change of file extension is... interesting. Are you looking for a quick way to put on your resume that you have done some ASP.NET? :)

Comment: No I want to mislead people, they shouldn't know that i have developed in j2ee.

Comment: Call `ServletContext.getrequestDispatcher("...").forward(...)` from a `Servlet` that is mapped to the urls you want to redirect.

Comment: @BevynQ: This has to written for every servlet please add your view on my answer.

Comment: map it to `*.aspx` then in the servlet extract a substring from the url and insert it into the url for the jsp you want to forward to. Should only need one with a small amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Struts url mapping feature for this.

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.aspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mislead the users then you don't have to aspx particularly. Many websites have an extension of `.do` or `.action` you can use any of them.

My choice to achieve it would be using `Spring Framework`. I will create a `Controller` with `@RequestMapping("/order.jsp")`.

I will have

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="suffix" value=".aspx" />
</bean>
```

In my `beans.xml` file. Which will make sure that you get proper link on the address bar.

**NOTE**: I am using Tomcat v6. I am not including all other details. For more details do a quick search on `Spring`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Servlet Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) you can change the extension of the respnse URL

AND

To access the URL based on Extension you can go for the [Servlet Mapping](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html).